# Return a value of 1 if linq query count returns zero

Tags: c#, linq

Looking for an alternative to writing the following query.

```
this.MaxExpoConsultTypes = expos.Any() ? expos.Max(e => 
  Math.Max(e.ExpComments
    .Where(c => c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD != null && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != "" && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != "?")
    .GroupBy(c => c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD)
    .Count(),1)) : 0;
```

The Math.Max function won't work because expos is an IQueryable and SQL will not be able to translate it, but is there to show how I want the results to return.

If the query returns a count of zero, I would like to reset it to 1.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "Obviously the `Math.Max` function won't work"
Why? Are you trying to accomplish something different than "if count is 0 return 1 otherwise return count"?

Comment: FYI, `c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD != null && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != ""` could be replaced by `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD);`

Comment: As @V0ldek said it is very unclear what you are asking `Max(count,1)` indeed seem to be returning what you described... Unless you are looking for `count ==1 ? 1:0`... Please [edit] question to clarify, ideally with simple code and exact examples of input/output - using `List<int>` should be enough to demonstrate what you are looking for and would be  much simpler to setup...

Comment: `var bob = LINQ; if (bob == 0) bob = 1;`

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about the fact that `expos.Max(e => Math.Max(...))` will not be translatable to SQL, if `expos` is an `IQueryable` against EF or something. It would be helpful if that was more explicit in the question.

Comment: Yes @HereticMonkey is correct, apologies about clarity, it does not translate to SQL

Comment: @Hank you can convert the query to in-memory collection first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer to your question would probably be to use your query as a subquery and then perform a projection that turns all 0s into 1s.

However, there is no gain in making the query more complicated to be executed against the database. Semantically, you're trying to find the `expo` with the highest number of comments satisfying a predicate, but you treat no comments as one instead of zero. The only way this is going to affect the end result is if for all `expos` you get a count of zero (because you `Max` over all of them). Thus, you can simply do this:

```
if (!expos.Any())
{
    this.MaxExpoConsultTypes = 0;
}
else
{
    var maxCount = expos.Max(e => 
      e.ExpComments
        .Where(c => c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD != null && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != "" && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != "?")
        .GroupBy(c => c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD)
        .Count());
    this.MaxExpoConsultTypes = maxCount != 0 ? maxCount : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any() resolved your problem

```
this.MaxExpoConsultTypes = expos.Any() ? e.ExpComments
    .Where(c => c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD != null && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != "" && c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD.Trim() != "?")
    .GroupBy(c => c.CMT_CNSLT_TYP_CD)
    .Count() : 1;
```